# Using isNaN in my code?

Tags: javascript

just recently started working with Javascript, and my only bump has been in the following:

```
var isEven = function(number) {
    if (number % 2 === 0) {
        return true
    }
    else if (number % 2 !== 0) {
        return false
    }
    else (isNaN) {
        return "Not a Number"
    }
};
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to implement isNaN as a function in this statement. I've tried so many things, and I know it's so simple, but it just isn't jumping out. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: `else if(isNaN(number)) {`

Comment: You can't have an else statement with conditions.

Comment: Use it as `isNaN(number)`. Code: `var isEven = function(number) { return +number % 2 === 0; };`

Comment: @Tushar You don't even need the `+`, because `"foo" % 2" is NaN, which is not equal to zero.

Comment: Using `else if(isNaN(number))` tells me that I need to make sure I am passing a string if the function input isn't a number, even though I am telling it to `return "blahblah"`, can anyone explain this?

Comment: Why do you need `isNaN` there at all? Is there a particular case when `NaN` is passed there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. When you pass a string, it returns "Not a Number". First you need to check if it is isNaN(number) and then continue with the rest of the cases.The order in which your following returns false even though it is not a number since (number % 2 !== 0) executes first , it evaluates,passes this condition and returns false.

```
 var isEven = function(number) {
   if(isNaN(number)) {
       return "Not a Number";
   }
   else if (number % 2 === 0) {
       return true;
   }
   else /*you can simply use else instead of else if(number%2!== 0) to find if it is not even since it is the last case*/
   {
       return false;
   }

 };
var ddd = isEven("hhh");
 console.log(ddd);
```

Comment: Well, yes and no. First, the third condition (`if (number %2 !== 0)`) is not necessary, because it will always be true at that point. Second, you don't really even need the `if (isNaN(number))` condition, because `number % 2 === 0)` will always be false if the number is NaN.

Comment: @torazaburo, but if reduce `if (isNaN(number))` function return `false` instead `"Not a Number"` so changed expected behavior

Comment: In that case, all you need is `if (isNaN(number)) { return "Not a Number"; } else { return number % 2 === 0; }`, or `return isNaN(number) ? "Not a Number" : number % 2 === 0;`.

Comment: @torazaburo I think now the code is more optimised.

Comment: It's better, but you are still using the "boolean return anti-pattern", where someone writes `if (b) return true; else return false;`. It is best practice to simply write `return b;`.

Comment: yes, you are right, but the person who questioned just wanted to know why his NAN condition wasn't working even when he passed a string. I just modified according to his code in order to make him understand. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the purpose of `isNaN`. The purpose of `isNaN` is to check whether something is equivalent to the **value** `NaN`.
It is *not* supposed to be used to check whether an arbitrary value is a number or not, and you shouldn't use it for that purpose.

To check whether a value is not of type `number`, use:

```
if (typeof number !== 'number')
```

to check whether a value is either a number or a string represending a number, you can use this:

```
if(isNaN(Number(number)) || 
   (typeof number !== 'number' && typeof number !== 'string'))
```

Example:

```js
var isEven = function(number) {
if(isNaN(Number(number)) || 
   (typeof number !== 'number' && typeof number !== 'string')) {
    return "Not a Number";
  }
  
  return number % 2;
};

console.log(isEven("1"));
console.log(isEven(13));
console.log(isEven("2"));
console.log(isEven(8));
console.log(isEven("What?"));
console.log(isEven([]));
console.log(isEven(false));
```